# Android Asynctask passing a single string

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to pass a single string into an asynctask. Could anyone show me how it is done? my getEntity needs The method getEntity(Activity, String, EntityGetListener) but I keep passing this String[]

```
String pass= story.get(position).getEntity();

        new RemoteDataTask().execute(pass);





private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EntityUtils.getEntity(activity, params, new EntityGetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGet(Entity entity) {

                viewcount = entity.getEntityStats().getViews();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocializeException error) {

            }
        });
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: pass `params[0]` instead of `params` to `getEntity` method for more information see [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You already have this

```
     new RemoteDataTask().execute(pass); // assuming pass is a string
```

In `doInbackground`

```
     @Override
     protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {   

             String s = params[0]; // here's youre string
             ...      //rest of the code. 
     }
```

You can find more info @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Update**

Asynctask is depecated. Should be using kotlin coroutines or rxjava or any other threading mechanism as alternatives.

Comment: When passing the `String value` into `AsyncTask` class, It says the variable is accessed from within an inner class. Need to be declared as final. But I need change variable values time to time. How can I fix this issue

Comment: @EJChathuranga if you are accessing a variable that is not a class variable and it is accessed in annonymous inner class it has to be final. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class. You can make the variable a  member of class initialize before use to overcome this

Comment: when I try to call new RemoteDataTask().execute it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'execute'". can you show me a way to solve this

Comment: @AbdulhakimZeinu you should ask a new question

Answer (score 6):

You can build `AsyncTask` with a constructor.

```
public class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Long> {

    private String data;

    public RemoteDataTask(String passedData) {
        data = passedData;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
        // you can access "data" variable here.
        EntityUtils.getEntity(activity, params, new EntityGetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGet(Entity entity) {
                viewcount = entity.getEntityStats().getViews();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(SocializeException error) {
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the application (`Activity`, `Service` etc), you can use;

```
private RemoteDataTask mTask;
private void doStuff(){
    String pass = "meow"; // story.get(position).getEntity();
    mTask = new RemoteDataTask(pass);
    mTask.execute();
}
```